# Is it possible to modify the gwei of an internal transaction?

Tags: solidity, transactions, gas

I am developing a contract that allows users to withdraw funds but I want to send them faster so I'm wondering, how can I modify the transaction gas price (gwei)?

```
(bool sent, bytes memory data) = payable(msg.sender).call{value: withdraw_amount}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to let them withdraw funds faster, since that will depend on the gasPrice they send along with the transaction. The gasPrice is something that I believe is not controllable by code and entirely dependent on the signer. All you can do is modify the gas-stipend, although that does not seem to be what you are looking for.